# Rails include module in model trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have module in **/lib/models/scopes.rb**

```
module Models
    module Scopes
        extend ActiveSupport::Concern
        ...
    end
end
```

I'm trying to include it from model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Models::Scopes
end
```

And getting error:

> NameError: uninitialized constant User::Models

How to solve this trouble? Maybe it`s wrong to keep this types of files in /lib?

Environment:
Rails v3.1
Ruby v1.9.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rails doesn't require files in the `lib` directory automatically, but you can add to the autoloaded paths in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Restart the server to pick up the new settings.

This will now load the file automatically when the module name is *first* used. In development mode, you might want to reload the module after *every* change in order to see the changes without restarting the server. To do that, add it as an eager load path instead:

```
config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

The scope shouldn't be a problem as long as you don't have a `Models` class or module *within* `User` or anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

when you define your class, you're "opening" a new scope. So when you do `Models::Scopes`, ruby is looking for `User::Models::Scopes`. You can fix this by using `::Models::Scopes`, the `::` telling ruby to look in the global scope.

FYI: I'm not sure about the terms I used or even if my train of thought if correct; but the solution should be good anyway. I'd think Ruby would try for `::Models::Scope` after failing to find `User::Models::Scope`, but it doesn't.. Maybe there is a `User::Models` scope defined somewhere? Anyway, as you can see, I'm not yet familiar with those. You might want to dig on the subject if that interests you

Comment: Thank you for answer. But now, with ::Models:Scopes, Rails throw "NameError: uninitialized constant Models"

Comment: then you should refer to @SMWEB answer. I skipped the part where your is in `/lib`. You first code should have worked fine if your file was loaded.